# Problemas para retornar objetos no Parse utilizando android

Tags: android, heroku, parse

Estou com problemas para retornar os objetos utilizando Parse para me conectar no heroku. Quando pesquiso sobre retornar objetos, todo mundo me manda utilizar o seguinte código:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Players");
query.whereEqualTo("status", "active");
query.orderByAscending("lastName"); // By lastname ascending order
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    @Override

  public void done(List<ParseObject> players, ParseException e) {

    if (players != null) {
      // Success - players contain active players

    } else {

      // Failed

                          } 

             }  

});
```

Para que ele retorne uma lista de ParseObject e apartir daí capturar as informações. Porém, quando eu tento fazer isso o Android Studio diz que está errado. Quando aperto alt + enter para ver a solução, ele me dá a solução de adicionar as seguintes implementações:

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Players");
query.whereEqualTo("status", "active");
query.orderByAscending("lastName"); // By lastname ascending order
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

@Override
  public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {

  }

  @Override
  public void done(List objects, ParseException e) {

  }
```

}

Alguém sabe me dizer como tratar isso ou se tá correto? Desejo retornar todos os usuários que se encontra numa coleação no mongoDB que tá no Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para atualizar caso mais alguém passe por isso:

Consegui resolver isso adicionando "new FindCallback"<"ParseObject()">""(*SEM AS ASPAS*) no lugar de "new FindCallback()" como demonstrado abaixo.

Modo que deixei e funcionou:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
    query.whereEqualTo("ID_Professor", capturaIDprofessor());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> NomeAlunosList, ParseException {


    });
```